# Circuit(cyle)-hyperplanes in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, matroids

Im currently working in matroid theory problem involving graphs. A circuit-hyperplane in a matroid is a circuit with |r| elements in a Flat of |r-1|.
Translated into a graph the circuit-hyperplane will be a cycle or |r| edges on |n-1| vertecies. 
I've been playing around with their construction and have found that in a graph I cannot create two disjoint circuit-hyperplanes. 
My problem is I cant create/find a reason as to why. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction or a paper that will help.

Comment: Your definition of circuit-hyperplane doesn't make sense. A circuit-hyperplane of a rank $r$ matroid is a subset of the ground set that is both a circuit (a minimally dependent set) and a hyperplane (a closed set of rank $r-1$).